# Column compare and return values

Tags: pandas

I got two dataframes df1 and df2. I am comparing column values from dataframe one against many column values in df2 and returning unique  intersection without duplicates in another dataframe.

df1

```
       WORD    
0     This     
1       is    
2        a    
3    sample   
4  sentence   
5        to  
6     check  
7      NLP   
8        in   
9    python
```

df2

```
Noun    Verb
Car     stand 
Sample  sit
        walk
        run
        is
```

Expected output

df3

```
    Noun      Verb
    sample    is
```

I used the following code to get following result. Although it is round-about way of achieving the result it is not quite right. It returned verb values for every noun column matched which I clearly didn't want.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("2.csv")
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Word'], right_on=['Noun'])
print df3.drop('Verb', 1)

   Word  Noun
0  this  this
1    is    is
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `numpy.intersect1d`

```
pd.DataFrame([np.intersect1d(x,df1.WORD.values) for x in df2.values.T],index=df2.columns).T
Out[147]: 
     Noun Verb
0  Sample   is
```

If you want to using pandas

```
df2.mul(df2.apply(lambda x : x.isin(df1.WORD))).apply(lambda x : sorted(x)).iloc[[-1],:]
Out[159]: 
     Noun Verb
4  Sample   is
```