# Cliche matching - Spacy

Tags: python, regex, nltk, spacy

I try to hold a list of cliches in pandas dataframe and want to run it through a text file and find extact matches. Is it possible using spaCy?

Sample list held in pandas.

```
Abandon ship
About face
Above board
All ears
```

Sample sentence.

```
This is a sample sentence containing a cliche abandon ship. He was all ears for the problem.
```

Expected output:

```
abandon ship
all ears
```

It has to take care of case-sensitivities between list and sentences.

Currently i am using this approach to arrive at single word matches.

[Column compare and return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851482/column-compare-and-return-values)

```
pd.DataFrame([np.intersect1d(x,df1.WORD.values) for x in df2.values.T],index=df2.columns).T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for Spacy's [matcher](https://spacy.io/api/matcher), which you can read more about [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#rule-based-matching). It can find arbitrarily long/complicated sequences of tokens for you, and you can easily parallelize it (see the matcher documentation for *pipe()*). It defaults to returning the location of matches in text, though you can do anything with you want with the tokens you've found them, and can also add an `on_match` callback function.

That said, I think your use case is fairly straightforward. I've included an example to get you started.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en')

cliches = ['Abandon ship',
'About face',
'Above board',
'All ears']

cliche_patterns = [[{'LOWER':token.text.lower()} for token in nlp(cliche)] for cliche in cliches]

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
for counter, pattern in enumerate(cliche_patterns):
    matcher.add("Cliche "+str(counter), None, pattern)

example_1 = nlp("Turn about face!")
example_2 = nlp("We must abandon ship! It's the only way to stay above board.")

matches_1 = matcher(example_1)
matches_2 = matcher(example_2)

for match in matches_1:
    print(example_1[match[1]:match[2]])

print("--------")
for match in matches_2:
    print(example_2[match[1]:match[2]])

>>> about face
>>> --------
>>> abandon ship
>>> above board
```

Just make sure you have a recent version of Spacy (2.0.0+) because the matcher API changed recently.